# How to Get Id from SQLite without using Any Listener in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I want to fetch Student Id from SQLite. I am inflating All row on ListView and that ListView having Sliding layout. Now My query is How to get Student Id from Sqlite when I touch Present or Absent View from row ? My View is Here
[Please Click here to View List Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCAJf.png)

I have to fetch Id from Selected ListItem adn save that id to another table. For this My code is here

```
private void presentAttendance() {
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    dateFormatter.setLenient(false);
    Date today = new Date();
    String s = dateFormatter.format(today);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date is : "+s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String id_attende = "1";
    String query = "INSERT INTO ListAttendance(Date_Attendance,ATTENDANCE_ID) values ('"
            + s + "','"
            + id_attende + "')";
    sqlHandler.executeQuery(query);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date Saved ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

**Here id_attende  will get ID from SQLite. if I will use setOnClickListner Then I am able to get but On Touch that Item How can I get  Id. Please guide me.**

Answer (score 0):

Use Recycler view if you want touch and swipe functionality in list type data.

For drag and swipe check [this](https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo) ,

For click event check [this](http://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/).

Comment: Hey Thnxx for quick response. I am using this LIbrary and want to apply and want to fetch data from Sqlite when its Delete or More buttons is pressed. Every row have different id so I want to get id from row which i select. Please check this Library 

https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout

Comment: so that library have already delete functionality you can check demo provided by developer.

Comment: Brother I am Abel to get only Item Position. But I want to get Sqlite id to send id into another table